# How do I write a swift array that can make the same UIImage appear for all my dynamic cells?

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift, uiimage

For my dynamic prototype tableview I have 135 cells. So i created a variable array:

```
var myLife = Array(count: 135, repeatedValue: "My Cell")
```

I have a mycell.jpg that I want to display on every one of those 135 cells, but i ended up writing mycell.jpg 135 times in this array cos I only know of this way to write the array for images.

```
var myCellImage = ["mycell.jpg", "mycell.jpg", "mycell.jpg", "mycell.jpg",......]
```

Is there a better code? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Always the same image on each cell (row) ?

Comment: in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, on the cell you dequeue, `myCell.imageView= UIImage(named: "mycell.jpg")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a method called `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your `UITableView`. This method gets called for each cell.

So, in there you can set the picture once and it will be set for every cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!  {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCellIdentifier") as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier")
    }

    cell.imageView = UIImage(named: "mycell.jpg")

    return cell
}
```